# Partial derivatives - 2 variables and composite function

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Find $ \frac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial x^2} $ if

$$ z = f(u,v)$$

where $ u = \phi(x,y)$ and $v = \psi(x,y)$

I'm kinda lost. First, I just calculated

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z }{\partial u} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} + \frac{ \partial z}{\partial u} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$$

Simce,

$$ \frac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)$$

The only thing that I have to do is substitute and apply the derivative of product?

The answer was given using Newton notation to derivatives, and it is kinda confusing, so I don't know if my answer (or procedure) is correct. I did:

$$ \frac{\partial ^2z }{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial ^2 z}{ \partial u \partial x} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} + \frac{ \partial ^2 \phi }{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial z }{\partial u} + \frac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial v\partial x} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial ^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} $$

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want $$ \frac{\partial ^2z }{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial ^2 z}{ \partial u \partial x} \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \frac{ \partial ^2 \phi }{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial z }{\partial u} + \frac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial v\partial x} \left(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \frac{\partial ^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} $$
Since $\frac{\partial z }{\partial u}$ is a function of $\phi(x,y)$ as well. You need to apply chain rule again.

Comment: @mtiano Indeed, I forgot that $ \frac{ \partial z}{\partial u} $ and $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}$ are functions of x too. But in this case, I don't see how the only thing that changes in my answer is a square, since $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial u} \right) $

Comment: Because $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial u})=\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial u\partial x}\right)\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$. So I end up with two $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$ and hence the square.

Comment: @mtiano: There is something missing in your last comment (i mean, in your Latex equation)

Comment: Sorry, I messed up my edit too, but I think you can see what I mean.

Comment: Yes, I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thinkg you lost something in your computation. For $z=f(u,v)$, we can see that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$.

Note that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}$ are $2$-varialbe functions,
then $\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}=(\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u^2}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u\partial v}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x})\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}+(\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial v^2}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u\partial v}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x})\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}$